# Thread.join() not behaving as I expect. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

Running this code example from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm :

```
public class TestThread {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();

        ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo("Thread One", PD);
        ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo("Thread Two", PD);

        T1.start();
        T2.start();

        // wait for threads to end
        try {
        T1.join();
        T2.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("All threads are dead, exiting main thread");
    }
}
```

I expect the *"All threads are dead, exiting main thread*" to appear at the **end** of the entire output.

However, when I run it, the output is always at the beginning, like this:

```
Starting Thread One
Starting Thread Two
All threads are dead, exiting main thread
Counter of Thread-0 --- 5
Counter of Thread-0 --- 4
Counter of Thread-0 --- 3
Counter of Thread-0 --- 2
Counter of Thread-0 --- 1
Thread One exiting.
Counter of Thread-1 --- 5
Counter of Thread-1 --- 4
Counter of Thread-1 --- 3
Counter of Thread-1 --- 2
Counter of Thread-1 --- 1
Thread Two exiting.
```

If I remove the two join() statements, the output is exactly the same.

I thought that join() waits for the current thread (main process in this case) to die.

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE: I am posting here the rest of the code from the link provided at the beginning of this post:

```
public class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    PrintDemo PD;

    ThreadDemo(String name, PrintDemo pd) {
        threadName = name;
        PD = pd;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (PD) {
            PD.printCount(this.getName());
        }
        System.out.println(threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

and...

```
public class PrintDemo {
    public void printCount(String threadName) {
        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Counter of " + threadName + " --- " + i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `ThreadDemo`?

Comment: Can't be sure without seeing the code from the thread worker (and no, I'm not clicking through the link; the minimal code needed to address the question should be posted in the question).  My guess would be that output buffering might be getting the better of you.  If you make one of the threads do something that takes some time, does the main thread output still occur right away?

Comment: Probably the fact that it's a terrible tutorial, which has a thread starting from inside a thread.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I agree with you for *some* of articles at tutorialspoint. But what's wrong with threads starting other threads? Every thread you spawn in program will start from inside another (main) thread.

Comment: That's a serious flaw in the tutorial code: the `start()` method of `ThreadDemo` (which is already a `Thread`) starts **another** `Thread`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Take a look at this particular tutorial and see what the thread does. The `start` method is *overridden*. The thread itself is never actually started and there is no access to the thread that is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, ah, I see now. I thought you were saying in about "Thread from another thread" in general. That tutorial article is indeed flawed. If it really needed that internal thread, it should've at least joined on it.

Comment: It also demonstrates synchronization in a totally meaningless way (the common object used is not modified in any way, and the synchronization merely serializes the threads, thus the whole point of using threads vanishes). Never mind the pokemon catch and the capitalized variables... this tutorial should be killed with fire.

Comment: @javaguy I just posted the rest of the code. Thanks for any insights you can shed on this.

Comment: In addition to other comments, look at the `ThreadDemo` code in `start()`: it starts a *new thread* which is not the one you call `join()` on in the main method.  That's why the particular behavior you see occurs.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I just commented out the entire start() method in class ThreadDemo and now it works as expected. Never in my dreams had I thought that I will need to troubleshoot and bugfix code that is supposed to teach me... On the brighter side, this material is now much better understood and ingrained. :-) Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: If you notice the code, a new thread is created on every iteration inside the loop. So, the print method prints the output after finishing the first two threads which have been started from Main thread.

Comment: The takeaway:  Just because somebody names a class `SomeFricknThread`, that does not mean that you can trust it to act like a `Thread`.  This rule may generalized to other concepts outside the realm of multi-threading, but for some reason it is _especially_ true for classes that have "Thread" in their names

Comment: Just in general, I would be suspicious if I have a class that extends a Thread right from the start. There should be a very good reason to *extend* a Thread rather than just give it a Runnable work unit. Extending is for modifying behavior, not overriding a `run()`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov My last comment essentially rectified the issue. The first to summarize the flaws in this tutorial in an answer (i.e. not a comment) would get to have the Accepted answer. People should be warned from such tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to mark this questions answered, so I will be summarizing the comments to the OP that eventually solved the mystery:

1. The problem is not in  `TestThread`'s main() but rather in the `ThreadDemo` class.
2. More specifically, `ThreadDemo`'s start() method does not start itself. Instead, it instantiates a new `Thread`, then starts it. However, as a result of calling start(), JVM itself calls `ThreadDemo`'s run() which explains why we see "Thread One/Two exiting" at all.
3. *"All threads are dead, exiting main thread"* is printed before all other messages simply because the unnamed threads that were started by `ThreadDemo.start()` exit immediately.